# How do I allow one entry per 24 hours?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm using asp.net web forms and mssql . how do I to allow users entering the same credentials into the database only once per 24 hours.

I've logged the datetime
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8toqe.png

```
If user exists > 24 hours 
{
allow entry
}
else 
{
deny entry
}
```

Comment: Stop and think first. Define precisely what you mean by "per 24 hours". Do you have fixed boundaries for this period or does it depend on something else - for example, when the last time a user was logged in? If user x logs in at today at 23:10, what is the earliest point in time that user x can log in next? Tomorrow at any time or tomorrow at (or after) 23:10?

Comment: after the next 23:10, do not allow them to enter entry before that.

Answer (score 0):

A general idea would be to make a routine (either in c# or an sql procedure) which runs:
`select max(createdate) from table_of_your_screenshot where username=<username_entered>`.

If the value returned is less than 24 hours earlier than current time, exit/return error.